# Databinding failed to get View's height

Tags: android, view, android-databinding

Recently, I started new Android project with databinding library.
I tried to get height of view. This is previous code for getting view's height. It works fine.

```
emptyListAppView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAppEmptyViewHeight = emptyListAppView.getHeight();
                SLog.v(TAG,"mContactEmptyViewHeight =  " + mAppEmptyViewHeight);

            }
        });
```

Apply databinding will be:

```
        binding.emptyListView.post(()->{
        SLog.v(TAG,"emptyListView height = " + binding.emptyListView.getHeight());
    });
```

But when I applied databinding to get View's height, return value is 0. Why can't I get view'height with databinding?

Comment: When you get height of that view? Maybe you can try to add some delay before get height, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the searching. I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26255133/5856328
I hope anyone get the same problem can resolve it with above solution